# Clean up JSON response for markup

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs

I am getting a JSON response from a server whose data includes text with html markup.

This is causing a problem because I am not able to style my pages since the response already has html tags.

Is there an elegant way to handle this ? Or should I reconstruct the response by parsing it for tags ?

**Update**

So say the Json response has some key called `instructions` :

```
`instructions` : `"<strong>Please post relevant code</strong>. <p>We have no way to guess how exactly you're trying to use that JSON response</p>"`
```

Now when I will display this in my template (angularjs) , I will say :

```
<div class="alert alert-info">
    {{ response.Instructions }}
</div>
```

Now this will show up with the tags `strong` and `p` in my template. I want to remote those templates or at least be able to show them as it is . Right now my template is getting rendered with the tags, is there are way to include the tags from the response in my markup ?

Comment: Please post relevant code. We have no way to guess how exactly you're trying to use that JSON response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can use `ng-bind-html`. Will need to make sure `$santize` module is included as dependency.

```
<div class="alert alert-info" ng-bind-html="response.Instructions">
```

[See angular ng-bind-html docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angBindHtml)

Answer (score 1):

Just [parse the JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse), then do something with its contents:

```
data = JSON.parse(payload);
content = data["some"]["key]["in]["there"];
do_something_with_the_content(content)
```

You can then use a library, such as jQuery, to manipulate the tags before you insert them in the DOM.